# Call a function which expects arguments with SKAction.runBlock()

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm working with Swift and SpriteKit

I'd like to use SKAction.runBlock() to run a function that expect arguments :

```
class Tile : SKShapeNode
{
}

override func didMoveToView()
{
    let tile = Tile()
    tile.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(myFunc(tile)))
}

func myFunc(tile: Tile)
{
}
```

When I try to create a function that doesn't expect any argument, everything works fine, but the code above returns this:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type
>   'dispatch_block_t' (aka '@convention(block) () -> ()')

What am I not understanding ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With writing this sort of expression:

```
SKAction.runBlock(myFunc(tile))
```

You are passing the result of calling `myFunc(tile)`.

(I believe you do not think this code: `SKAction.runBlock(sin(0))`, would pass some sort of closure to `runBlock`.)

And the returned value from `myFunc(tile)` is a void value, as `myFunc` is declared to return nothing. A void value can be represented also as `()`. The error message says `()` cannot be converted to a closure of type `@convention(block) () -> ()`.

Thus, you need to create a closure of type `@convention(block) () -> ()`.

```
    tile.runAction(SKAction.runBlock({()->() in myFunc(tile)}))
```

in short:

```
    tile.runAction(SKAction.runBlock({myFunc(tile)}))
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation. So why can I call a function with no expected argument without having to put "{ }" ?

Comment: @Drakalex, in Swift, method references are automatically converted to a closure with the same function type. So, just writing `myFunc`, you are creating a closure of type `(Tile) -> Void`. So, if `anotherFunc` is declared as `func anotherFunc() {}`, writing `anotherFunc` creates a closure of type `()->Void` (same as `()->()`), which you may have seen before.

Comment: Functions are closures,  it is a special case closure,  so no converting happens.(ignore last comment,  I understand what you are saying now)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing {} Just:

```
 tile.runAction(SKAction.runBlock({
    myFunc(tile)}))
```